# Is there a way to underclock a nVidia chipset or GPU, to lower heat output?

Tags: windows-vista, nvidia-geforce, underclock

I have a hp G60-244dx, which features the nVidia GeForce 8200M G graphics chip, and nVidia nForce chipset.

It runs Windows Vista Home Basic.

I don't use this for anything beyond web browsing, email, reading news, etc. No heavy graphics use, no gaming.

Is there a reliable way to underclock the GPU, so as to reduce the overall heat generated by the laptop?

---

**EDIT:** I tried [nVidia's System Tools](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nvidia_system_tools_6.06.html), but I could only see how to overclock with that tool.  I want to underclock.

Right now I have an idle PC, doing nothing.  The nVidia GPU reads 72C (161F), which is extremely hot for doing NOTHING.  As a result the laptop's fan is constantly whirring at an audible level.  I don't need high performance graphics. I especially don't need the whirring sound.  How can I turn it DOWN?!?!!?

I would also consider modifying the DSDT for the ACPI BIOS, but I can't figure out how to do that either.

Comment: The sound of the fan is generally a good thing unless it is overactive due to a bad sensor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Troubleshoot your video card by underclocking](http://www.playtool.com/pages/underclockvid/slowdown.html) :

> If you have an NVIDIA card, then you
>   should start with [CoolBits](http://www.playtool.com/pages/underclockvid/slowdown.html#coolbits)
>   because it uses controls provided by
>   NVIDIA. If that doesn't work then you
>   can try [PowerStrip](http://www.playtool.com/pages/underclockvid/slowdown.html#powerstrip). If PowerStrip
>   has problems then you can try
>   [RivaTuner](http://www.playtool.com/pages/underclockvid/slowdown.html#rivatuner).

Comment: hmm, I will check out Coolbits and PowerStrip.  I tried RivaTuner but couldn't figure out how to get it to work for my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard good things about overclocking with [RivaTuner](http://www.guru3d.com/index.php?page=rivatuner), maybe it can underclock your GPU for you.

Thinking about it, this is something my work lappy could do with as well (Nvidia NVS 135), I'll try it next time I'm at the machine.

Comment: I tried RivaTuner, but it is so complicated, I couldn't figure out how to use it.   It is primarily targeted at overclocking, rather than underclocking. I did see a "tutorial" on using RivaTuner for underclocking but... the "Customize" button was not shown in the Rivatuner UI, on my laptop.  Another deadend.

Comment: You mentioned the nVidia System Tools, and I've found that it can underclock my laptop GPU, but not by much and the temperature difference is at best 2-3C cooler.  In my case it seems that the GPU, chipset and CPU all share a single cooler and the CPU getting hotter seems to heat the GPU up and so while the GPU runs hot I suspect the problem lies elsewhere (as in poor cooler design).

Comment: I would suspect that the nVidia System Tools is the best way to work with your card speeds, it certainly did allow me to underclock my GPU, and as it is supplied by nVidia I would trust it more than third party programs like RivaTuner.

Comment: can you post an answer with a description, plus maybe some screenshots showing how you set the underclocking with nVidia System Tools?  Or maybe refer to a how-to guide that you know of, sourced elsewhere?  I saw a response curve where I could overclock but did not see the underclocking option.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to the Power Settings, and looking at the advanced power settings. There should be options in there to help you out.

I don't have your hardware, but I have a laptop with an Intel and a nVidia gpu, and I was able to turn mine off, and there's a setting for telling the fan how to behave. Whether it should kick up the fan when the GPU is demanded, or whether it should just slow the GPU down. Some other interesting settings too that you might find useful are in there. If you came across a setting that you don't understand and you're afraid to change it, just google it, and you'll find a ton of sites explaining the setting in detail to you.